# How to retrieve only top rows per date

Tags: sql

I am trying to extract first row per date from a balance table. and I am trying to write an sql code but I cant get a clue from how can I do it..

I tried max, sum, group by.. but its not helping out.

```
Date         Account    Balance
4/6/2019    A           90
4/5/2019    B           80
4/4/2019    C           70
4/3/2019    C           60
4/2/2019    D           80
4/1/2019    D           100
```

So how can I make a query which will show the following results?

**Account Balance in April**

```
Account Balance
A           90
B           80
C           70
D           80
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First `group by account` to get the max `date` for each `account` and then join to the table:

```
select t.acount, t.balance 
from tablename t inner join (
  select account, max(date) maxdate
  from tablename
  group by account
) g on g.account = t.account and g.maxdate = t.date
```

Answer (score 1):

use analytic function first_value if your dbms support

```
 select Account,
 FIRST_VALUE(balance) OVER (partition by Account ORDER BY date desc) AS balance
 from table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use a sunquery for max date

```
select account, balance 
from  (
  select  accont, balance, max(date)
  from my_table 
  group  by  accont, balance
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

A canonical method would be filtering in the `where` clause:

```
select b.*
from balances b
where b.date = (select max(b2.date)
                from balances b2
                where b2.account = b.account and
                      b2.date >= '2019-04-01' and
                      b2.date < '2019-05-01'
               );
```

Specific databases may have other approaches to this problem.  The above generally has very good performance, particularly with an index on `balances(account, date)`.